# Changing response doc object from findOneAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Say I got this lil chunk of code:

```
 Room.findOneAndUpdate({ Roomid: roomid }, { $push: { UsersMeta: UserMeta}}, { new: false }, function (err, room) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log('room output:');        
    console.log(room);
    client.emit('others', room);
 })
```

which is searching for one  document in db, updates it, and then sends this `room` doc in pre-updated state back to client. What I need is to make some changes to responded `room`, particularly remove those _id, __v, and, possibly, any other custom part of doc.

What I was trying to do:

use `toObject.transform` while creating schema

```
var RoomSchema = mongoose.Schema({
Roomid: { type: String, unique: true },
///stuff///
});

RoomSchema.options.toObject.transform = function (doc, ret, options) {
// remove the _id of every document before returning the result
delete ret._id;
}
```

failed: recieved `cannot set property 'transform' of undefined` error.

Change mentioned chunk of code to:

```
 Room.find({ Roomid: roomid })
.update({ $push: { UsersMeta: UserMeta} })
.select({ _id: 0 })
.exec(function (err, room) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log('room output:');
    console.log(room);
    client.emit('others', room);
})
```

Failed: always recieve [] in `room` output.

Now I stopped at manually setting `{_id: false}` on Schema declaration, completely getting rid of `_id` in the first place. As I want use custom random id's for rooms, it seems that I don't need those `_id` anyway. Yet I'm not sure, that such a treatment will not cause some unpleasant consequences.
And, moreover, problem of possible need to leave some non `_id` doc properties out of response  - is an unsolved mystery for me.

Thank you for attention.

Comment: Also, was trying to simply `delete room._id` - no effect, as I understand, due to `room` being mongoose doc, not a simple JS object.

Comment: You need to add something like this, before you try to set the `toObject.transform()`:   `if (!schema.options.toOjbect) schema.options.toObject = {};`

Comment: I feel a bit ashamed, but i do not understand what this code part even do, can you explain? Why i need to define options.toObject as an empty object?
And when this transform will be called, each time i somehow trying to recieve schema's doc as any kind of respose?

Comment: Attempting to set/retrieve a property of `undefined` throws a `TypeError`.  So, the above code first creates `schema.options.toObject`, before trying to set the `transform` property of it.

Comment: Ok, just seems strange, why, if `options.toObject.transform = function (doc, ret, options)` is supported feature - `toObject` is not defined by default. Yet still it just a way to get rid of _id that i dont need constantly, but if i need to leave behind different properties of document in different cases?

Comment: I see what you mean, it is slightly strange, but that's just how it is: schema doesnt' have default `toObject`, you have to define it yourself.

Comment: why are not you preparing a new object like room before emitting to the client?

Comment: If you mean just construct a `room` object for emmiting from the parts of response, that i got; like `rooms = {foo: respone.foo, bar: response.bar}` - in fact, I was doing this before, is this a way to go and there is no more 'elegant' way to do this in one short and funky db call?

Comment: Well if to think about this with a clearer mind, I spent way too much hours stuck in one place. Maybe I just trying to hammer a nail with a rocket launcher. Anyway waiting for reply still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the following and it should work;

```
RoomSchema.set('toJSON', {
   transform: function (doc, ret, options) {
     delete ret._id;
     delete ret.__v;
   }
});
```

Comment: As i understand this will set a general behavior of any `RoomSchema` docs to delete those parts. But what is the best way, in my case, to filter different parts of `RoomSchema` docs in different calls.

Comment: you can delete room.someProp but make sure to call toJSON before that, like room.toJSON() to covert mongoose object to json object and then call delete

Comment: Ah ok, and this `RoomSchema('toJSON'... transform: function` will be called only when i'm tryin to `room.toJSON()` ?
And what is difference between `toJSON` and `toObject` mentioned above in `schema.options.toObject.transform = function` ?

Comment: it seems like you forgot `.set` adter `RoomSchema` http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toJSON

Comment: This approach will work, therefore marking this as accepted.
Yet i'm better off with `toObject`, as `aarosil` suggested in the comments to my original question, adding `if (!schema.options.toOjbect) schema.options.toObject = {};` made it, and now everything is nice clean and filtered each time i console.log it or send it to the better places, without any need to call `toJSON`.
Btw, `Safi`, maybe you will be so kind to look at my another related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727079/mongoose-node-js-how-to-find-populate-do-stuff-depopulate-and-update ?